# MapStruct to generate file for Objects implementing Iterable<T> interface

Tags: java, mapstruct, mapper

I have a give scenario :

```
class Curve implements Iterable<Point> {

  protected String curveName;
  protected Date curveVersion;
  protected String curveType;
  protected List<Point> points; 

  <!--- public getter&setters  --->
}


class Point {

  protected int x;
  protected int y;
  protected int z;

   <!--- public getter&setters  --->
}
```

When I create a mapper abstract class/interface for Curve class like below :

```
public abstract class CurveMapper {

 CurveMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CurveMapper.class);

 protected abstract com.entity.Curve map(com.dto.Curve);

}
```

The auto generated CurveMapperImpl class only creates mapping for Point class fields which is in Iterable. All fields of Curve class (subclass) are ignored except point field.

Eg :

```
public class CurveMapperImpl implements CurveMapper {

 @Override 
 public com.entity.Curve map(com.dto.Curve arg0) {

  if (arg0 = bull)
   return null;

  com.entity.Curve curve1 = new com.entity.Curve();
  for (com.dto.Point point : curve.getPoint()) {
   curve1.add(covertPoint(point));
  }
}

protected com.entity.Point convertPoint(com.dto.Point point) {
  com.entity.Point point1 = new com.entity.Point();
  point1.setX(point.getX);
  point1.setY(point.getY);
  point1.setZ(point.getZ);

 return point1;
}
```

All fileds like **`curveName`**, **`curveVersion`**, **`curveType`** are not mapping. Even after trying **`@Mapping`** annotation with source and target, its not working. But if I remove implementation **`Iterable<Point>`** it works. I cannot modify the Object classes as they are coming from library.

How can I solve this. Any workaround?

Comment: Can you share with us the dto class?

Comment: @LoreloreloreThe dto class is same as entity class. Absolutely no difference.